# angular bootstrap ui tabs select option not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have overriden angular ui tabs directive, the following is the plunker fro the same http://plnkr.co/edit/VABthzUwp50QpS16Gwuy?p=preview. Now my requirement is that when I select a tab, I need the callback function to be invoked. Hence I used the select attribute of the tab directive.

```
<tab title="Tab 1" select="alertMe()" template-url="tab1.html"  active='data.static1'></tab>
```

In my controller I have put an alert in my function, howeevr the function doesnt seem to get called.Here is the overriden directive.

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.tabs', [])
.directive('tabset', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.templateUrl = '';
      var tabs = $scope.tabs = [];
      var controller = this;

      this.selectTab = function (tab) {
        angular.forEach(tabs, function (tab) {

          tab.selected = false;
        });
        tab.selected = true;
      };

      this.setTabTemplate = function (templateUrl) {
        $scope.templateUrl = templateUrl;
      }

      this.addTab = function (tab) {
        if (tabs.length == 0) {
          controller.selectTab(tab);
        }

        tabs.push(tab);

      };
    },
    template:
      '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
          '<div class="nav nav-tabs" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
          '<ng-include src="templateUrl"></ng-include>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>'
  };
})
.directive('tab', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    require: '^tabset',
    scope: {
      title: '@',
      templateUrl: '@',
      onSelect: '&select'
      //active: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsetController) {
    scope.$parent.$watch($parse(attrs.active), function (value) {

      if (value) {
        tabsetController.selectTab(scope);
      //   scope.onSelect();
      }

    });

      tabsetController.addTab(scope);

      scope.select = function () {
   alert()
        tabsetController.selectTab(scope);
       // scope.onSelect();
      }

      scope.$watch('selected', function () {

        if (scope.selected) {
          scope.onSelect();
          tabsetController.setTabTemplate(scope.templateUrl);
        }
      });

    },
    template:
      '<li ng-class="{active: selected}">' +
        '<a href="" ng-click="select()">{{ title }}</a>' +
      '</li>'
  };
}]);
```

Is there any way to call this callback method?

Comment: You have posted 13 questions on this site and several have viable answers yet you have not marked any of them as answered.  Please take the time and mark your previous questions as answered where appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Tab directive you need to set the callback function on the scope like so:

```
scope: {
  title: '@',
  templateUrl: '@',
  select: "&"
  //active: '='
},
```

See this plunkr for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3GVxq5elw8aIgjQKMsQ?p=preview

Comment: I tried with,however it does not seem to call my callback function.Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the function be called scope.alertMe() rather than scope.select()?